# How to have this folder structure working as Python modules?

Tags: python, module

I have two projects, organized according to the following structure

```
core
 * src
   * main
     * python
       * module
         * __init__.py
         * tools.py
extension
 * src
   * main
     * python
       * module
         * submodule
           * __init__.py
           * usercode.py
```

Consider both `src/main/python` are in `PYPATH`

Unfortunatly, when I do `import module.submodule.usercode`, all I get is

```
ImportError: No module named submodule
```

How can I fix that ?

**EDIT 1**

Notice I want to use the `tools.py` from my core module alongside the `usercode.py` from my extension ... which, according to python module loading mechanism, make it impossible for me to have a `__init__.py` file in my `extension/src/main/python/module` folder, like most answers suggested.

**EDIT 2**

I have to elaborate a few things here

- In production mode, the Python code is extracted by a maven process and assembled into a simple folder looking more or less like

  - module

    - **init**.py
    - tools.py
    - submodule
    - **init**.py
    - tools.py
- In dev mode, both projects exist separatly, and I run code from `extension/src/test`.

Obviously, my issues only exist in dev mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I used an `__init__.py` in test classes, to have code from `core` copied into `extension` at test start, and removed at test end. For code distribution, I rely upon some maven magic.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [`packages`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

So to treat `module` directory as a package, you need to add a `__init.py__` file inside it:

```
extension
 * src
   * main
     * python
       * module
         * __init__.py # add this file to treat the directory as a module
         * submodule
           * __init__.py
           * usercode.py
```

**UPDATE:**

From the folder pattern you use, it looks more like an organization for a `java` project. In `python` you don't really need such a complex structure. But if you really want to have this structure you would need to add `__init__.py` to all the folders there are.

But what I would suggest is this:

```
core
   * __init__.py
   * module
     * __init__.py
     * tools.py

extension
   * __init__.py
   * module
     * __init__.py
     * submodule
         * __init__.py
         * usercode.py
```

And then you can import like following:

```
from core.module import tools
```

or,

```
from extension.module.submodule import usercode
```

Do notice the `__init__.py` file in each directory, though I removed some of the directories to make the structure look more pythonic.

Comment: Edited question to indicate why this solution isn't usable for me (but I upvoted your answer nevertheless, cause it's the best one so far)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your python packages have an `__init__.py` in them:

```
extension
 * src
   * main
     * python
       * module
         * __init__.py # You're missing one here
         * submodule
           * __init__.py
           * usercode.py
```

Comment: Edited question to indicate why this solution isn't usable for me.

Comment: @Riduidel which module are you using both in? What's the folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

module also needs an `__init__` file so it would be a python package and not a regular directory